# Log all the information about an exception

Tags: python-3.x, exception

How can I write a **log entry** – serialising information to text – that **captures all the useful information about an exception**?

In Python 3, exception instances got considerably more awesome, but also more complex. They can have a `__cause__` or not, can have a `__context__` or not, they can have a `__traceback__` or not, they have a type, and probably more wrinkles that I'm missing.

The information needed to diagnose an exception later can include any or all of this. It can also, of course, include the same information for any related (cause, or context, or …?) exception instance, recursively.

At the point of logging a caught exception (prior to re-raising it), what **single “get me all the information” technique** is there which I can use to record the *full* **diagnostic information contained in the exception object, as text** which will be useful to the eventual diagnosis effort?